# Setting TargetServerVersion property for an SSIS project to 2014 globally in VS2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssdt-bi

When creating a new SSIS project in VS2015 the default TargetServerVersion is set to SQL Server 2016 by default. I would like to set this to SQL Server 2014 as (a global) default.

[image]

Also when I need to have a quick look at the package and simply open an SSIS package it uses the default of SQL Server 2016 which causes a conversion to be triggered which is not what I want. I did not find a specific setting in the Options Settings for Business Intelligence Designers. 
Any help appreciated.